# npm compilation error ('_' is not defined)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, react-bootstrap

I have been updating all the dependencies in my js program but did not change anything with any of my components. However now when I run

```
npm run build
```

I get an error with one of my components which says:

```
Failed to compile.

./src/components/DonationSummaryComponent.js
  Line 14:  '_' is not defined  no-undef

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.


npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! my-app@0.1.0 build: `react-scripts build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the my-app@0.1.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Itay\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-09-17T08_25_54_825Z-debug.log
```

I tried

```
npm i lodash
```

But this did not solve the problem.

Here is the component which the error is about:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {Alert} from 'react-bootstrap';
import {MonthlyDonations} from './MonthlyDonationsComponent.js';


export class DonationSummary extends Component {
  render() {
    var monthsComponents = [];

    var monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
                  "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];  

    if(this.props.yearData.length > 0){
      var monthsdata = _.groupBy(this.props.yearData, function(dataEntry) {
        return(monthNames[(new Date(dataEntry.donationDate)).getUTCMonth()]);
      });      

      for (var monthName in monthsdata) {
        if (monthsdata.hasOwnProperty(monthName)) {
          monthsComponents.push(<MonthlyDonations key={monthName+this.props.year} monthName={monthName} monthData={monthsdata[monthName]}/>);
        }
      }
    }
    else{
      monthsComponents.push(<Alert key="noDonations" bsStyle="info"> there are no donations to display </Alert> );
    }
    return(
      <div>
        {monthsComponents}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

line 14 which the error refers to is:

```
var monthsdata = _.groupBy(this.props.yearData, function(dataEntry) {
```

The error might be related to the fact that I updated react-bootstrap react to latest version (16.5.0). Both are being used in this component.

Comment: You need to import lodash lib as import _ from 'lodash';

Comment: Yep, my bad. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to import lodash library in your component

PFB working code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {Alert} from 'react-bootstrap';
import {MonthlyDonations} from './MonthlyDonationsComponent.js';
import _ from 'lodash';

export class DonationSummary extends Component {
  render() {
    var monthsComponents = [];

    var monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
                  "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];  

    if(this.props.yearData.length > 0){
      var monthsdata = _.groupBy(this.props.yearData, function(dataEntry) {
        return(monthNames[(new Date(dataEntry.donationDate)).getUTCMonth()]);
      });      

      for (var monthName in monthsdata) {
        if (monthsdata.hasOwnProperty(monthName)) {
          monthsComponents.push(<MonthlyDonations key={monthName+this.props.year} monthName={monthName} monthData={monthsdata[monthName]}/>);
        }
      }
    }
    else{
      monthsComponents.push(<Alert key="noDonations" bsStyle="info"> there are no donations to display </Alert> );
    }
    return(
      <div>
        {monthsComponents}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not importing lodash in your component.

You should add `import _ from 'lodash';` and it will work

Answer (score 1):

You need to import lodash library.

> import _ from 'lodash'

I would recommend to use [lodash.groupby](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash.groupby), which will also decrease bundle size. Please install this package and import it:

> import groupBy from 'lodash.groupby'

and then use:

> var monthsdata = groupBy(this.props.yearData, function(dataEntry) {